# Where is the IPA on the Mac (when it's used as a build server)?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

On Visual Studio version 16.6.1 (on Windows), when building a Xamarin.iOS app with a Mac as a build server, the "Show IPA File on Build Server" option is grayed out.

So where can I find the IPA on the Mac?

(I already searched in the Mac's HD -> Library -> Caches , but there is no "Xamarin" folder there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong **Library** folder.

You need to go to `~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/`. Then the builds will be in `mtbs/builds` folder.

Where `~` is your user's base directory.

NB: Keep in mind that the user's `Library` folder is hidden, so you will need to either show the hidden files (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>), or to navigate through the terminal or with Finder's `Go to folder...` options (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> or through the menu *Go --> Go To Folder...*).

Comment: Where is that `~`? When Finder starts there are only 2 "folders" there: the HD, and "Network".

Comment: Those are the builds but no IPA files exist in those folders.

Comment: @ispiro `~` refers to the user's home directory on unix-like systems.